# conditional statement in ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, syntax

I am trying to write Helper method in rails but its throwing error for following line

```
#if button_source.kind_of?(Array) then list = button_source else list = button_source.sort
```

The complete code

```
def buttons(model_name, target_property, button_source)
html = ''
list = ''
if button_source.kind_of?(Array) then list = button_source else list = button_source.sort end
list = button_source.sort
list.each do|x|
    html << radio_button(model_name, target_property, x[1])
    html << h(x[0])
    html << '<br />'
end
    return html
end
```

Please help me to resolve this issue, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You're missing an end at the end of the if statement.

Comment: yes right, i have noticed that, but still getting another error while using `<%= buttons(:person, country_array) %>` in view

Comment: You pass 2 args but your method requires 3